# Sort an integer array, negative integers in the front and positive integers in the back

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I was given an array like this:

```
$input = array(-1,1,3,-2,2, 3,4,-4);
```

I neeed to sort it in such a way that negative integers are in the front and positive integers are at the back, and the relative position should not be changed. So the output should be:

```
$output = array(-1 ,-2,-4, 1,3,2,3,4);
```

I tried this using `usort`, but I could not retain the relative positions.

```
function cmp ($a, $b)
{
    return $a - $b;
}
usort($input, "cmp");
echo '<pre>', print_r($input), '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => -4
    [1] => -2
    [2] => -1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4
)
```

Comment: where the -4 in the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this..

```
$arr = array(-1,1,3,-2,2, 3,4,-4);


$positive = array_filter($arr, function($x) { return $x > 0; });
$negative = array_filter($arr, function($x) { return $x < 0; });

sort($positive);
rsort($negative);

$sorted = array_merge($negative,$positive);
print_r($sorted);
```

Demo:https://eval.in/419320

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => -2
    [2] => -4
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4
)
```

Comment: This is almost correct, except OP doesn't want the values sorted. Leave off the sort and combine the `$positive` and `$negative` arrays, and you're golden. Like this: https://eval.in/419328

Comment: Thanks for the idea, your approach I tried it using array_map , but it is returning null arrays for me.
https://eval.in/419331

Comment: @Stuart Wagner ya i accept your thoughts but the negative values may be reordered for other probabilities

Comment: You need to use closure for your example [check this using array_filter](https://eval.in/419355) and [using array_map](https://eval.in/419365) @Srini

Comment: @srini I've posted both answers using `array_map` and `array_filter`

Answer (score 2):

This is an *ordering* problem, but it's not a *sort*.

The problem can be broken down as follows:

1. Separate the given array into two arrays; one of negative numbers, the other of positive numbers. (Should consider where you want `0`.) The order of items in each of those arrays should be the same as they appear in the input array.

   Do this by `push`ing values, for example.
2. Concatenate the two arrays.